# Check if a string in a list is between two other strings in a list?

Tags: python, pandas, list

```
import pandas as pd
    
nameBank = ["John Doe", "Jane Doe", "Patrick Star", "Spongebob Squarepants"]
phoneList = []
nameList = []

list1 = ["1234567890", "John doe", "Not a NAME/USELESS FILLERINFO",  "2345678901", "jane doe", "Not a NAME/USELESS FILLERINFO", "Not a NAME/USELESS FILLERINFO", "3456789012", "4567890123", "5678901234", "patrick star", "6789012345"]

df = pd.DataFrame({'Phone Number': phoneList, 'Name': nameList})
df.to_csv('results.csv', index=False, encoding='utf-8')
print(df)
```

What I want to do is retrieve from this list1 is each phone number and put that into the `phoneList`.

From there I want to see if there is a name from the `nameBank` that is in the list after the current phone number and before the next phone number in the list.

If there is a name after a phone number, then I want to be able to append it to the `nameList`,
if there is no name after a phone number, then i want to append "No Name Found" to the `nameList`.
So it can essentially correspond in an excel chart.

i.e the phone number `1234567890` has the name John Doe corresponding to it between the two lists. The second phone number has the name Jane Doe attached to it so when you use these two lists to create a table using pandas they will correspond.
The third phone number `3456789012` has no name in between itself and the next phone number in the list, therefore I want the appended value to the nameList to be `"no name found"`.

Essentially what the output table would look like:
[image: chart example]

Comment: Your sample code produces an empty `df`.

Answer (score 0):

So, you want to parse list1 into a Series:

```
list1 = ["1234567890", "John doe", "Not a NAME/USELESS FILLERINFO",  "2345678901", "jane doe", "Not a NAME/USELESS FILLERINFO", "Not a NAME/USELESS FILLERINFO", "3456789012", "4567890123", "5678901234", "patrick star", "6789012345"]


import re

num = re.compile('\d{10}')
output = {}
i = 0
while i < len(list1):
    if not num.match(list1[i]):
        i += 1
        continue
    output[list1[i]] = list1[i+1] if i+1<len(list1) and not num.match(list1[i+1]) else 'not found'
    i += 1
    
series = pd.Series(output)
```

Output:

```
1234567890        John doe
2345678901        jane doe
3456789012       not found
4567890123       not found
5678901234    patrick star
6789012345       not found
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

nameBank = ["John Doe", "Jane Doe", "Patrick Star", "Spongebob Squarepants"]
list1 = ["1234567890", "John doe", "Not a NAME/USELESS FILLERINFO",  "2345678901", "jane doe", "Not a NAME/USELESS FILLERINFO", "Not a NAME/USELESS FILLERINFO", "3456789012", "4567890123", "5678901234", "patrick star", "6789012345"]

data = []
for index, elem in enumerate(list1):
    if elem.isnumeric():
        if (len(list1) - 1) > index:
            if list1[index+1].casefold() in map(str.casefold, nameBank):
                data.append([elem,list1[index+1].title()])
            else:
                data.append([elem, 'No Name Found'])
        else:
            data.append([elem, 'No Name Found'])
 
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Phone Number', 'Name'])      
# df.to_csv('results.csv', index=False, encoding='utf-8'     
print(df)
```

output:

```
  Phone Number           Name
0   1234567890       John Doe
1   2345678901       Jane Doe
2   3456789012  No Name Found
3   4567890123  No Name Found
4   5678901234   Patrick Star
5   6789012345  No Name Found
```

Comment: Thank you everyone for the replies. They have been extremely helpful! What do you think you would do if the name wasn't always right after phone number? Say for example: list1 = ["1234567890", "Not a NAME/USELESS FILLERINFO",  "John doe"  "2345678901", "jane doe", "Not a NAME/USELESS FILLERINFO", "Not a NAME/USELESS FILLERINFO", "3456789012", "4567890123", "5678901234", "Not a NAME/USELESS FILLERINFO", "Not a NAME/USELESS FILLERINFO", "Not a NAME/USELESS FILLERINFO", "patrick star", "6789012345"]

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
import pandas as pd

list1 = ["1234567890", "John doe", "Not a NAME/USELESS FILLERINFO",  "2345678901", "jane doe", "Not a NAME/USELESS FILLERINFO", "Not a NAME/USELESS FILLERINFO", "3456789012", "4567890123", "5678901234", "patrick star", "6789012345"]
nameBank = ["John Doe", "Jane Doe", "Patrick Star", "Spongebob Squarepants"]

def mapList(list1):
    output = []
    for index, item in enumerate(list1, start=0): 
        if re.match("^\d{10}", item):
            # Use any one condition             
            # if index < len(list1) - 1 and list1[index + 1] in nameBank:
            if index < len(list1) - 1 and not re.match("^\d{10}", list1[index + 1]):
                output.append([list1[index], list1[index+1]]);
            else:
                output.append([list1[index],'No Name Found']);
    return output;


df = pd.DataFrame(mapList(list1), columns=['Phone Number', 'Name'])      
print(df)
```

Output:

```
  Phone Number           Name
0   1234567890       John doe
1   2345678901       jane doe
2   3456789012  No Name Found
3   4567890123  No Name Found
4   5678901234   patrick star
5   6789012345  No Name Found
```